# Angular 2 Router wait for animation to complete on component before destroying it on route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to create a module that listens to route changes and on route change executes a given animation based on the current route and the go-to-next route. Basically it should solve this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845 
Like this (draft notes): https://github.com/bergben/ng2-page-transition/issues/6

Now to do this, I want to execute a given animation via the route data on enter and on leave of a component. This animation can vary depending on the current route and the next route. So for example switching to `/main` from `/first` could trigger a go-back-animation whilst switching to `/main`from `/second` could trigger a go-forth-animation.

Now to the problem: How can I bind this animation to the component and allow it to complete? 
The router renders a component like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<my-current-component>...</my-current-component>
```

But on route change it immediately destroys `<my-current-component>...</my-current-component>`and replaces it with the new component.

I know that binding animations to the host in the Component decorator like this: https://github.com/designcourse/angular-auth-demo/blob/master/src/app/login/login.component.ts#L11
allows them to complete. But I can't change the Component on route change (it's a constant, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#component-anchor)

I should mention that I found out that wrapping another element around the rendered component like

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>
   <my-current-component>...</my-current-component>
</div>
```

prevents the router from destroying the component. Accessing the DOM directly isn't a best practice though. I would only consider that as a last resort. If someone knows how to wrap a `<div></div>` around the component via the Angular Renderer or ViewContainerRef's etc. then I'd be happy to hear about that. Then I could bind the animation to that `<div></div>` wrapper and manually destroy it after the animation has completed.

**The animation should be executed without delaying the new components entering animation.**

So I was hoping someone might have an idea / suggestion on how to accomplish this in the best way possible.

Comment: Looking for an answer myself... I suggest looking at animation callbacks though.